# PowerShell to find all empty AD Security Groups with no Members OR Computer Objects

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am currently running this script:

`Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq 'Security'} | ?{@(Get-ADGroupMember $_).Length -eq 0} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\177626\EmptySG.csv"`

It technically is working by pulling all of the Security Groups without members but it is still pulling groups that have Computer Objects in the Members list. Is there anyway to modify this to filter out those groups that have those Computer Objects in them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `Get-ADGroup` to provide more than just the default attributes. One of them is "Members". You can use the property `.count` to determine if the group is empty or not.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Security'" -Properties Members |
    Where-Object {$_.Members.count -eq 0}
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately that is still pulling in some Security Groups with Computer Objects in the Members List

Comment: I don't know what to say. I just tested it and in my environment computer accounts contained in security groups are counted just like normal user accounts. So the code I posted works just as expected for me. Are you sure we are talking about the "Members" attribute and not about the "MemberOf" attribute?